# Accessing the array values in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I need to access the array elements, from the below array structure.Here i need to access the NewsFeedComment array.I am trying to do this, but it's giving me the error Undefined index: comments

How can i access the elements in the NewsFeedComment array

```
In Controller:
$this->set('newsfeed',$this->paginate('NewsFeed',$newsfeed));

In view:

<?php foreach ($newsfeeds $newsfeed): ?>
<div class="news_reply_display">
<?php echo $newsfeed['NewsFeedComment'][0]['comments'] ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>


array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'NewsFeed' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'title' => 'Best Restaurant',
        'group_id' => '1',
        'posted_message' => 'message.',
        'user_id' => '11',
        'created' => '2013-12-03 09:35:02',
        'status' => 'A'
    ),
    'Group' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'group_name' => 'My group',
        'created_user' => '1',
        'created_date' => '2013-04-24 15:31:09',
        'privacy' => '0',
        'membership' => '0',
        'description' => 'desc'
    ),

    'NewsFeedComment' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'news_feed_id' => '2',
            'comments' => 'comment1',

            'status' => 'A'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'news_feed_id' => '2',
            'comments' => 'comment2',

            'status' => 'A'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'news_feed_id' => '2',
            'comments' => 'comment3',

            'status' => 'A'
        )
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'NewsFeed' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'title' => 'Test Subject',
        'group_id' => '1',
        'posted_message' => 'description.',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'created' => '2013-12-03 08:25:12',
        'status' => 'A'
    ),
    'Group' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'group_name' => 'secondgroup',
        'title' => 'Second Grouups',
        'group_slug' => 'secgroup',
        'created_user' => '1',
        'created_date' => '2013-04-24 15:31:09',
        'privacy' => '0',
        'membership' => '0',
        'description' => 'desc'
    ),

    'NewsFeedComment' => array()
)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

That index doesn't exist. In that particular case you must use $newsfeed[0]['NewsFeedComment']['comments'].

Now, if you would like to extract all "NewsFeedComent" arrays from $newsfeed then you can use [Hash::extract](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3aextract)

```
$newsFeedComments = Hash::extract($users, '{n}.NewsFeedComment');
debug($newsFeedComments);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($newsfeeds as $newsfeed){ 
   foreach($newsfeed['NewsFeedComment'] as $NewsFeedCommentData){

       echo $NewsFeedCommentData['comments'];

   }
 }
```

Using the above code you will get comments corresponding to each index of array $newsfeeds

Comment: Thanksss for the reply